# Multiple Blue Screen of Death (BSOD)

Tags: windows-10, bsod

My PC crashes (BSOD) ~2 times a day at arbitrary times, between 1 minute and 3 hours after startup. Each time I get a different error message. The last 3 that I remember were:

- KMODE_EXCECPTION_NOT_HANDLED
- SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION
- SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION (win32kfull.sys)

I've had 2 other BSOD messages that I've forgotten that are different to the above.
This is making it different to address, since I can't just google a single BSOD message to find a solution, and each BSOD message I google has different proposed solutions.
I have a new PC (3 months old) and these problems started happening 1 month ago. I haven't installed new drivers or anything just before it started happening.
Any ideas?

Comment: Run the memory test built into windows 10.

Comment: This utility https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html will check the dump and provides a way to do a web search on the cause.